# Why is a TTT diagram called isothermal transformation diagram?

Tags: physical-chemistry, metal, metallurgy

Why are TTT diagrams called isothermal temperature diagram?As far as I know the temperature variation is plotted with the variation of time in a TTT diagram. Then why do we call it "isothermal".What is so constant about the temperature?

Comment: They are there to show you what happens while holding a sample at fixed temperature for different times. For non-isothermal conditions they are not particularly useful as normally presented.

Comment: “*Put up in a place / where it's easy to see / the cryptic admonishment / T.T.T. / When you feel how depressingly / slowly you climb, / it's well to remember that / Things Take Time.*” ([Piet Hein, T.T.T.](https://allpoetry.com/T.T.T.))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are two names for the same procedure.  A steel is heated to a temperature in the austenite range then quenched/quickly cooled to some specific temperature. Held at that constant ( isothermal) temperature ( T) for a specific time (T) then quenched to room temperature for examination of the transformation (T) products.  You may be thinking of CCT ; continuous cooling diagrams ; where a steel sample is austenitized  then continuously cooled at some specific rate.  Then examined for transformation products. The results can have similarities depending on alloy content , etc.